# Invalid date on CSV import

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm getting an error `Mysql2::Error (Invalid date: 2005-10-00)` when trying to import a csv file. It works fine locally, but on my staging server it doesn't. My csv lists the date as `DD/MM/YY` and on conversion i'm trying to match what MYSQL likes.

```
if params[:table]
    table = params[:table]
    Table.destroy_all
    CSV.foreach(table.path, :headers => true, encoding:'iso-8859-1:utf-8') do |row|
      Table.create!(
 :date => row[1].nil? ? nil : Date.strptime(row[1], "%d/%m/%y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
 )
end
```

Could this be an encoding issue with my staging database?

Comment: Maybe the data you are rendering was wrong. On your error, it says this: `Mysql2::Error (Invalid date: 2005-10-00)` so if you take a look, their is no `00` value for date.

Comment: I thought of that, but even when I only try one entry with no change of having '00' it still doesn't work.

Comment: Probably sg goes wrong in the conversion of the date in the `Date.strptime(row[1], "%d/%m/%y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` expression and the day value is incorrectly parsed.